# Python datetime add a time

Tags: python, datetime

I've a time like: 08:44:11 and I'll add 2h and 4min. but my Python script doesn't work, what's wrong?

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

s1 = '08:44:11'
s2 = '02:04:00'

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

## works
# tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)

## did not work, but why?
# tdelta = datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) + datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)

## works but i got also a year ....
#print datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) +  timedelta(seconds=120, FMT)

print tdelta
```

Comment: if you have a year why not simply add 365 days?

Comment: if you just want to add or subtract time, just use time instead of datetime

Answer (score 1):

The reason the addition isn't working is because the `date` object represents a calendar date while a `timedelta` object represents a duration or difference between dates or times.

The subtraction works because you are taking two `date` objects and subtracting them to get a `timedelta` object. For example Jan 2 - Jan 1 = 1 day.

For addition to work, either one or both of the values being added needs to be a `timedelta` object. For example, Jan 1 + 1 day = Jan 2 or 1 day + 2 days = 3 days. It doesn't make much sense to say Jan 1 + Jan 2.

In your example, both `s1` and `s2` would be `timedelta` objects (since they don't have associated calendar dates) so you can do the following for addition:

```
td1 = timedelta(hours=8,minutes=44,seconds=11)
td2 = timedelta(hours=2,minutes=4)

td3 = td1 + td2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding datetime instead of time. When I inspect with pprints, it's show as followed;

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 4)
```

which mean you're setting a datetime of 1/1/1990 02:04:00 and if you set another, it'll be the same date with different time. So, you can subtract it because it'll end up remaining hours but if you add to each other how the date will handle it.